# What is stored near the heap-break (end of uninitialized segment)?

Tags: c, unix, memory, heap-memory

In this simple code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    void * first = sbrk(4096);
    void *p = sbrk(0);

    //sigterm, however were it (p-4) -> it could be derefenced
    *((int*)(p-3)) = 1;
    printf("%d\n",*(int*)(p-3));
}
```

If I am trying to dereference address near the end of heap, I get segfault. However B-16 (where B stands for heap break) is dereferencable, whereas B-12 is not (segfault). So what information is stored near the break of heap?

Comment: The expression `(p-3)` is undefined behavior.  Perhaps you meant to cast that `p` to an `int *` rather than casting `p - 3`.  Regardless, this question is going to be implementation dependent, so if you want an answer you'll need to give platform details.

Comment: You can't do arithmetic on void pointers.

Comment: You've taken the address of the end of the heap, subtracted three from it and read four bytes from there. Including one byte from after the break. There is no page above the break, hence the segfault.

Comment: This is heavily system dependant. It is an old BSD 4.3 function that was removed from POSIX.1-2001. It mainly exists as an internal function for malloc, and is considered legacy because it assumes that the data segment is contiguous and unique. The linux man page says: *On Linux, sbrk() is implemented as a library function that uses the brk() system call, and does some internal bookkeeping*. So it seems reasonable that the system library gives you not the true end of segment but the end of what you can use. Use above at own risk...

Comment: It isn't p-12 and p-16, it's p-3 and p-4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't doing p-12 and p-16, you're doing p-3 and p-4.

You are doing `(int*)(p-3)` i.e. you are subtracting 3 and *then* converting to int, not the other way around, `((int*)p)-3`. So the compiler subtracts 3 of whatever type `p` is declared to point to, not 3 ints.

That type is `void` since `p` is a `void*`. So the compiler subtracts 3 bytes. Then you read 4 bytes since `int` is 4 bytes on your compiler.

*Note:* subtracting from `void*` is a GCC-specific extension - an extra feature that's not part of normal C. Some compilers will give you an error saying you can't add or subtract `void*` pointers. On those compilers, to subtract 3 bytes, you would have to cast to `char*` and then subtract 3.